# I just started studying selenium and xpaths and i need a safer locator for the label with string "Some Option"

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<label class="style_status_msg">Some Option:</label>
```

Previously, I used xpath to locate this element and check for availability.

```
Boolean isPresentPS = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='id_version_status']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/label[17]")).size() > 0;
```

But this may not be the best option since if other elements before this is not present, checking may result to false results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these below xpath:

**Explanation:** Use `class` attribute of `label` tag, along with `text` method.

```
//label[@class='style_status_msg'][contains(text(), 'Some Option:')]
```

OR
**Explanation:** Use `text` method along with `label` tag.

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Some Option:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select required element by text content:

```
//label[text()="Some Option:"]
```

If you want to match element just by partial text content:

```
//label[contains(text(), "Some Opt")]
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Thanks